# pkg-config doesn't work on Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, configure, pkg-config

I try to compile a program ([OpenFP](http://open-fp.sourceforge.net/)) using cygwin. The program depends on a package `FFTW3` which I've compiled and installed succesfully. However when I launch `./configure` for the main program I get an error:

> No package 'fftw3' found configure:6138: error: Package requirements
>   ("fftw3") were not met: No package 'fftw3' found Consider adjusting
>   the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in
>   a non-standard prefix. Alternatively, you may set the environment
>   variables FFTW3_CFLAGS and FFTW3_LIBS to avoid the need to call
>   pkg-config. See the pkg-config man page for more details.

`pkg-config --list-all` doesn't find `fftw3` library but `/usr/local/lib/pckconfig` contains required `.pc` file. Ok, from that file fftw3.pc i copied `LIBS` and `CFLAGS` parameters into `FFTW3_CFLAGS` and `FFTW3_LIBS` evironment variables as the error message above prompted. However I'm still getting the same error.

What's wrong?

P.S. Setting variables the same way in MinGW solved the problem (I have not installed pkg-config in MinGW), but compilation of the project failed due to the lack of some linux-specific headers in MinGW)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `/usr/local/lib/pckconfig` to your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

This tells `pkg-config` to look in an additional location, besides its standard path.

Comment: Thanks for your answher. I had to mention that I tried to do so but with no effect. However I solved the problem changing this variable to native windows path!!! i.e `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=c:\\cygwin\\usr\\local\\lib\\pkgconfig`

Comment: @Andrey It's empty for me "C:\cygwin64\usr\local\lib\NOTHINGisHERE"; But 'cygcheck -c' shows pkg-config is installed!

Comment: @AndreySboev, For me the native Windows path in PKG_CONFIG_PATH does not work. For example, /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/pkgconfig works, but C:\\Cygwin64\\usr\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\sys-root\\mingw\\lib\\pkgconfig does not work. I use pkg-config 1.6.3 (C:\Cygwin64\bin\pkgconf.exe). I wrote also in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037850/4807875 about it.