# g++: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, cygwin

I installed cygwin and followed this for installation http://cs.calvin.edu/curriculum/cs/112/resources/installingEclipse/cygwin/

then I run this on my cmd

```
cd opencv
cd sources
cd samples
cd cpp
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` facedetect.cpp -o facedetect
```

It resulted into this

```
g++: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
g++: error: opencv`: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--cflags'
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--libs'
```

what I'm trying to do is to run facedetect.cpp in opencv to test my classifier any help to fix this issue or provide alternative approach is appreciated

Comment: You probably have to install `pkgconfig` on your system.

Comment: isnt pkgconfig included in cygwin?

Comment: It should be selectable as an option when you run the setup program. Else these posts may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930394/pkg-config-command-not-found-using-cygwin-on-windows-7 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307339/pkg-config-doesnt-work-on-cygwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the packages *pkg-config* and *libopencv-devel*

http://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/pkg-config

http://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libopencv-devel

Comment: sorry for the noob question but how do I download it from this website?

Comment: @RedViper use `setup.exe` or `apt-cyg`

Comment: Its already installed, I run cygcheck -c and its there but its still not working