# Install node and opencv on windows 8 using NPM

Tags: node.js, opencv

I seem to be having issues installing opencv with npm on windows 8 and was wondering if anyone could offer some pointers.

Errors are as follows, I know the obvious is install pkg-config but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this?:

```
    C:\Users\Marc>npm install opencv
\
> opencv@0.5.0 preinstall C:\Users\Marc\node_modules\opencv
> node-gyp clean rebuild


C:\Users\Marc\node_modules\opencv>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\n
pm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean rebuild

'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --libs opencv' returned exit status 1. while trying to
load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "clean" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Marc\node_modules\opencv
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.30
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! opencv@0.5.0 preinstall: `node-gyp clean rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv@0.5.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the opencv package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp clean rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls opencv
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "opencv"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Marc
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Marc\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Rachel you'd be my favorite person in the entire world if you can - I kinda gave up on it but would love to finish this project!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm still working on getting this going in win8 with VS2013, but I found several of the dependencies I needed at http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php.  You can find pkg-config there and some other things that it depends on.  An answer that has all of what I've already done is at [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows).  I'm dealing with different problems now, but I hope this helps!

UPDATE

I got it working now on my laptop.  I believe the secret, after getting pkg-config and its dependencies all installed, was the opencv.pc file.  It has to point to your installation of opencv, and point by version to a bunch of the libs.  Here's what ended up in mine:

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=C:/OpenCV249/opencv
exec_prefix=${prefix}/bin
libdir=${prefix}/build/x64/vc11/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/build/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/build/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 2.4.9
Libs: ${libdir}/opencv_core249 ${libdir}/opencv_imgproc249 ${libdir}/opencv_highgui249 ${libdir}/opencv_ml249 ${libdir}/opencv_video249 ${libdir}/opencv_features2d249 ${libdir}/opencv_calib3d249 ${libdir}/opencv_objdetect249 ${libdir}/opencv_contrib249 ${libdir}/opencv_legacy249 ${libdir}/opencv_flann249
```

Cflags: ${includedir_old} ${includedir_new}

I placed this file in its own folder, and then created the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable with that folder as its value.  If I get feeling ambitious, maybe I'll see if I can get it working with OpenCV 3.0.0.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Bob lemmy know how you get on since I was about to revisit this!