# What is the best way to install pkg-config on Mingw in 2014?

Tags: windows, mingw, pkg-config

What is a good way at this moment (October 2014) to install [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) on Windows in a *(no HTTPS)* [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) / [MinGW-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/) environment? (See also [this question from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows).)

If there is a binary package that does not pull in GTK+, that would be great, but I haven't found one. Building from source is fine if that's the way to go.

On the [Mingw FAQ](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ) it says: (This is from 2009 the latest, judging from a comment at the bottom of the page.)

> How do I get pkg-config installed?
>
> The difficulty in getting pkg-config installed is due its circular depency on glib. To install pkg-config, you should first install the GTK-runtime, the installer is found at *(dead link)* https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=121075. The pkg-config binary can be obtained from *(new link, but does not mention pkg-config)* https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php. Place pkg-config.exe in your MinGW bin directory.
>
> There are other pkg-config projects that don't have the circular dependency issue. They include:
>
> - *(dead link)* [pkgconf](https://github.com/nenolod/pkgconf)
> - [pkg-config-lite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pkgconfiglite/files/)

I've quickly looked at pkg-config-lite, but it looks like it was last updated in 2012. Also, I think pkg-config now includes its own version of Glib to break the circular dependency, so it should be possible to build without Glib.

I've done searches for "mingw pkg-config". Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: For building from source, see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/pkg-config.rb for the Homebrew formula (interesting: `./configure --with-internal-glib`).

Answer (score 16):

The way to go seems to be MSYS2 and MinGW-w64. [Download MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), on 32-bit Windows run `msys32\autorebase.bat` (this should not be needed much longer), then:

```
pacman -Syu  # to update the system packages
```

([these errors are not fatal](https://gist.github.com/felixrabe/24d26493d93a6096b333)), then

```
pacman -Ssq pkg-config  # to list pkg-config packages

#  for 64 bit:      ------
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config

#  for 32 bit:      ----
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to compile this package for days and it turns out all I needed was MSYS2 and `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config` !

Comment: This answer is not about enabling `pkg-config` tool on a MinGW compiler setup but rather to have a MSYS2 based environment which provides both the compiler and tool in its own way. Good one however.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `mingw-w64-` versions of `pkg-config` use `;` as separator in the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable, while the MSYS2 version (`pacman -S pkg-config`) uses `:`.

Answer (score 5):

On https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/message/31908633/ there are some instructions from earlier this year:

> The FAQ pkg-config information did not work for me:
>   these did:
>   https://github.com/texane/stlink/issues/169
>
> Download these three glib, pkg-config, pkg-config-dev archives and
>   extract contents to C:\MinGW
>
> *(These are all dead links – see also [another SO question regarding win32builder.gnome.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478651/can-anyone-access-http-win32builder-gnome-org):)*
>
> http://win32builder.gnome.org/packages/3.6/glib_2.34.3-1_win32.zip
>
> http://win32builder.gnome.org/packages/3.6/pkg-config_0.28-1_win32.zip
>
> http://win32builder.gnome.org/packages/3.6/pkg-config-dev_0.28-1_win32.zip

I keep this unaccepted in case someone has a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is also pkg-config-lite:

1. Install [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)
2. Install [pkg-config-lite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pkgconfiglite)
3. Set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the directory containing your *.pc files (i.e. c:\mingw64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig)

Comment: The value of `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is the info I was missing, thanks.