# can anyone access http://win32builder.gnome.org?

Tags: mingw, gnome

Trying to download the following, however, I can't seem to access the links from Work, Home and Cell. Anyone know of any alternative sites? trying to get the below packages into MinGW.

[glib_2.34.3-1_win32.zip](http://win32builder.gnome.org/packages/3.6/glib_2.34.3-1_win32.zip)

[pkg-config_0.28-1_win32.zip](http://win32builder.gnome.org/packages/3.6/pkg-config_0.28-1_win32.zip)

[pkg-config-dev_0.28-1_win32.zip](http://win32builder.gnome.org/packages/3.6/pkg-config-dev_0.28-1_win32.zip)

Comment: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com

Comment: Thanks, "It's not just you! http://win32builder.gnome.org looks down from here"

Comment: still down.... ive contacted them and no responce. any ideas where i can get the files?

Comment: I've used the [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180719181100/http://win32builder.gnome.org/) site to access the files. Works for me.