# Error:Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

Tags: cmake, point-cloud-library, pkg-config

I am using Point cloud library 1.5.1. When I run CMake 3.4.0-rc2 to build my project, it has error:

```
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/717302/cmake-could-not-find-pkgconfig-missing-pkg-config-executable)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This error is raised because the [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) utility is not available on your system.

Using `PkgConfig` with CMake is not a truly cross-platform solution, as Windows does not come with the `pkg-config` utility installed. (The PCL developers should instead use `find_package()` in their CMake. Perhaps, this is worth opening up a bug report on their Github.) On Linux, this is an easy fix; you can install `pkg-config` like this:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

However, on Windows, the process is more involved. There are several solutions for installing `pkg-config` on Windows documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1710922/3987854). I'm not sure which most directly applies to your situation, so I suggest reading through some of those. After successfully installing the `pkg-config` utility on your Windows machine, clear your CMake cache, and re-run CMake. This should remove the error, and allow your build to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Install vcpkg: https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html

Install pkgconf:

```
 .\vcpkg install pkgconf
```

If use CMake, delete the Cache files/folders: `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeFiles`. After that, run the command

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\dev\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake
```

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora 34, it was because of multiple pkg-config

```
/home/sapillai/go/bin/pkg-config
/home/sapillai/go/bin/pkg-config
/usr/bin/pkg-config
/home/sapillai/go/bin/pkg-config
```

I deleted the others and kept `/usr/bin/pkg-config`.  Error was gone.