# Node openCV installation

Tags: node.js, opencv, installation

[image]

I would like to install *OpenCV* in windows to get the library in *NodeJS*. But I am recurrently having some issues.

> Failed at the OpenCV@5.0.0 install "node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build.

This is most likely a problem with *opencv* package.

What is the way to get the Peterbraden package installed with avoiding this error message? Command is `npm install opencv`.

Below is the output in a file after running command:

> opencv@5.0.0 `install C:\node_modules\opencv
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
>
> C:\node_modules\opencv>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   clean )  else (node "" clean )
>
> C:\node_modules\opencv>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   configure --fallback-to-build
>   --module=C:\node_modules\opencv\build\opencv\v5.0.0\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32\opencv.node
>   --module_name=opencv --module_path=C:\node_modules\opencv\build\opencv\v5.0.0\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32
>   )  else (node "" configure --fallback-to-build
>   --module=C:\node_modules\opencv\build\opencv\v5.0.0\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32\opencv.node
>   --module_name=opencv --module_path=C:\node_modules\opencv\build\opencv\v5.0.0\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32
>   )  Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build
>   --module=C:\node_modules\opencv\build\opencv\v5.0.0\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32\opencv.node
>   --module_name=opencv --module_path=C:\node_modules\opencv\build\opencv\v5.0.0\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32'
>   (1)

Comment: can you show the whole output from npm i ?

Comment: provided ! Please respond if you are aware on this.

Comment: please provide: `cwd`, your `npm i` command, then please run redirect npm output to  file then post the file content. `npm [...] 1> output.msg 2>&1`

Comment: provided....!! -mh-cbon

Comment: -  Thanks for editing the question. Answer is important to me. Please provide if you know. - Aleksander Azizi

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues even using virtual boxes prepared to be used with OpenCV and node.js - both Vagrant and Docker.

After few sleepless nights I somehow figured out what was wrong on my machines. First I tried to figure out if OpenCV is installed and where.
I was troubleshooting on Linux (Centos) and on Mac OS X.

Solution for me was:

- install OpenCV libraries
- add environment variables **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** with path to file */opencv.pc*     .../opencv/lib/pkgconfig
- make sure **pkg-config** was installed

Ok that was Unix systems. Windows are a bit different but checklist is probably about the same.

1. OpenCV installed
2. System environment variables set:
   As described in documentation you need to set **system variables**.

That can be done in *Computer* > *Properties* > *Advanced System Settings*

In *System properties* windows click *Advanced* tab and then E*nvironment Variables* button.

In Environment Variables add to System Properties:

**OPENCV_DIR** with value: **C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc12**
**PATH**  append to your path: **;%OPENCV_DIR%\bin**

3. Build tools installed
   Make sure Visual Studio installed with **C++** compnents!

If all above is check, then perhaps you can also check if **pkg config** is installed: [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Erik. Let me check tonight and I will update you soon if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue yesterday. I believe the build script is no longer properly installing node-gyp and node-pre-gyp. Here are the steps I completed to resolve the build errors. These steps force the installation of both of those dependencies both globally and at the project level.

1. Be sure you only have python 2.7 installed on you machine and
   that    is an environment var
2. you need to global 'npm i -g
   node-gyp    node-pre-gyp'
3. in terminal/cli/powershell, navigate
   to the    node-opencv project
4. need to project 'npm i -S node-gyp
   node-pre-gyp'
5. npm install (to build the project)
6. in terminal/cli/powershell to the target/consuming project
7. 'npm i -S node-gyp node-pre-gyp'
8. finally, 'npm -i -S opencv'

Hope you have the same success I did.

Comment: It is both 'node-gyp' AND 'node-pre-gyp'. Both of these must be installed globally and within the project. You may install both in one shot be entering what I have suggested. That is, type 'npm i -g node-gyp node-pre-gyp' into your terminal/cli.