# Getting error: " 'pkg-config' is required to install this package" while installing eth-testrpc

Tags: python, pip, ethereum

I am trying to install TestRPC for Ethereum on my Windows machine via MobaXterm terminal using pip [Reference: https://github.com/pipermerriam/eth-testrpc] as follows:

> pip install eth-testrpc

But I get the following error:
  Using cached secp256k1-0.13.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    'pkg-config' is required to install this package. Please see the README for details.

Unable to resolve it. It says "pkg-config is required. Does it mean the package: pkgconfig. This one is already installed:

```
[manindra.singh] ➤ pip install pkgconfig
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pkgconfig in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Full command execution:

```
    [manindra.singh] ➤ pip install eth-testrpc
Collecting eth-testrpc
  Using cached eth-testrpc-0.8.4.tar.gz
Collecting gevent>=1.1.2 (from eth-testrpc)
  Using cached gevent-1.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from eth-testrpc)
  Using cached Werkzeug-0.11.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click>=6.6 (from eth-testrpc)
  Using cached click-6.6.tar.gz
Collecting ethereum-tester-client>=1.2.1 (from eth-testrpc)
  Using cached ethereum-tester-client-1.2.2.tar.gz
Collecting ethereum>=1.5.2 (from eth-testrpc)
  Using cached ethereum-1.5.2.tar.gz
Collecting json-rpc>=1.10.3 (from eth-testrpc)
  Using cached json_rpc-1.10.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rlp>=0.4.4 (from eth-testrpc)
  Using cached rlp-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting greenlet>=0.4.9 (from gevent>=1.1.2->eth-testrpc)
  Using cached greenlet-0.4.10.zip
Collecting repoze.lru (from ethereum>=1.5.2->eth-testrpc)
  Using cached repoze.lru-0.6.tar.gz
Collecting PyYAML (from ethereum>=1.5.2->eth-testrpc)
  Using cached PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz
Collecting pysha3 (from ethereum>=1.5.2->eth-testrpc)
  Using cached pysha3-0.3.zip
Collecting pbkdf2 (from ethereum>=1.5.2->eth-testrpc)
  Using cached pbkdf2-1.3.tar.gz
Collecting bitcoin (from ethereum>=1.5.2->eth-testrpc)
  Using cached bitcoin-1.1.42.tar.gz
Collecting pycryptodome>=3.3.1 (from ethereum>=1.5.2->eth-testrpc)
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.4.tar.gz
Collecting secp256k1 (from ethereum>=1.5.2->eth-testrpc)
  Using cached secp256k1-0.13.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    'pkg-config' is required to install this package. Please see the README for details.
```

Comment: ... No, it means pkgconfig from your distro.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio, it helped. Installed pkg-config as mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows and this issue is solved. Getting some other problem. Will post a new query if unable to solve that.

Comment: also experiencing this problem.
which of the answers in the linked stackoverflow worked?
pkg-config-lite looks was last updated in 2013

Comment: @aspiringGuru: Answers by ismail and hyperQuantum worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install eth-testrpc with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688655/cant-install-eth-testrpc-with-pip3)