# XMLSEC installation error, Windows-7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pkg-config, xmlsec

Im trying to install xmlsec (with pip) but it is throwing: error: pkg-config is not installed. Im using Python3.6 on windows 7.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Xmlsec has some issues with windows but as with python 3.6 and below the problem is solved. Use this link to download the wheel file for your python version https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/releases

Install the wheel file using

```
pip install <wheel_file_name>
```

As with Python 3.7, the only way out is to install xmlsec on a Linux machine as it is not yet supported on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem on Windows @Jcc.Sanabria on Windows. Where as Linux & MAC are seems to be working for xmlsec.
Since I had gone through this situations for around weeks now.

Going through official Document 
[here](http://pythonhosted.org/xmlsec/index.html) I didn't find any instruction on "How to install this on Windows?"

To answer your question :
Resolve your exception related with **pkgconfig** you can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363820/8139861) on Windows.

But then it will also ask you to install Visual C++ (>=ver. 14.0) but after installing this too.
You will face exception like this one :
    "cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-error=declaration-after-statement'
    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2"

Which I didn't find any resolution till now. :(

But to use xmlsec and python on Windows working you need to take support from Cygwin. Where you can install all related packages from Cygwin Packages list for python and xmlsec dependancy. Following are the name & version of some packages :

gettext-devel(0.19.8.1-2),libglib2.0-devel(2.50.3-1),libxml2-devel(2.9.4-2),libxmlsec1-devel(1.2.24-1),libxslt-devel(1.1.29-1)

Further dependency can be checked on this [link](https://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html)