# Pycharm error 'pkg-config' is required to install this package on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, pkg-config

When I try to install a package in Windows Pycharm I get this error

```
Collecting secp256k1 (from sawtooth-signing->sawtooth-sdk==1.0.1)
  Using cached secp256k1-0.13.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    'pkg-config' is required to install this package. Please see the README for details.

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\secp256k1\
```

I ran **pip install pkgconfig** and it installed correctly but Pycharm fails with this same error. I followed the directions here [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows) but I still receive the error. How can I overcome this and install pkg-config?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've downloaded pkgconfig as described in your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows), you must also add the folder to your environment variables path.

In my case:

1. I downloaded and extracted pkgconfig to C:\Program Files (x86)\
2. I added C:\Program Files (x86)\pkg-config_0.26-1_win32\bin to my path
3. I put the required .dll files in the bin folder also.

Keep in mind you will have to restart in order for the changes to path to be effective.