# I setup pkg-config to path and stack still gives me file not found error. windows 10

Tags: windows, haskell, windows-10, haskell-stack, pkg-config

For sdl2 for Haskell, I went here [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows#22363820) and downloaded the pkg pkg-config-lite. I set it to path and it gives me this error `Configuring sdl2-2.4.1.0...
    Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5.exe: The pkg-config package 'sdl2'
    version >=2.0.4 is required but it could not be found.`

I tried to find a new replacement and failed to find one that worked.

````
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\e626a42b configure --with-ghc=C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.6.5\bin\ghc.EXE --with-ghc-pkg=C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.6.5\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=C:\sr\snapshots\a6aa7628\pkgdb --libdir=C:\sr\snapshots\a6aa7628\lib --bindir=C:\sr\snapshots\a6aa7628\bin --datadir=C:\sr\snapshots\a6aa7628\share --libexecdir=C:\sr\snapshots\a6aa7628\libexec --sysconfdir=C:\sr\snapshots\a6aa7628\etc --docdir=C:\sr\snapshots\a6aa7628\doc\sdl2-2.4.1.0 --htmldir=C:\sr\snapshots\a6aa7628\doc\sdl2-2.4.1.0 --haddockdir=C:\sr\snapshots\a6aa7628\doc\sdl2-2.4.1.0 --dependency=StateVar=StateVar-1.1.1.1-2ewTKofpCGhC2np5dyFIaR --dependency=base=base-4.12.0.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.2 --dependency=exceptions=exceptions-0.10.2-965Nx9KftkgCsZ4B7Zhuyu --dependency=linear=linear-1.20.9-8i87OQRLMk19j5jCRXHfj4 --dependency=text=text-1.2.3.1 --dependency=transformers=transformers-0.5.6.2 --dependency=vector=vector-0.12.0.3-2LEYu9M2i7lERDtz76XG3n --extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\mingw64\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\mingw64\bin --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\mingw64\lib
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: C:\sr\global-project\.stack-work\logs\sdl2-2.4.1.0.log

    Configuring sdl2-2.4.1.0...
    Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5.exe: The pkg-config package 'sdl2'
    version >=2.0.4 is required but it could not be found.```

the output should be it downloads sdl2 into my computer
````

Comment: There's SDL2 the actual library, which is written in C, `sdl2` the Haskell interface to the actual library, and `pkg-config` the tool the second one uses to find the first one. You have `pkg-config` installed, but did you install SDL2 the C library before trying to build `sdl2` the Haskell interface? You can find SDL2 [on its website](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php).

Comment: @HTNW I have sdl2 set to path with codeblocks. It still doesn't work