# How to fix the error,"ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:"

Tags: python, kivy

I tried downloading kivy on my windows desktop, but got the following error. What should i do?

```
enter code herecommand: 'C:\Users\arnav\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\arnav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coyz2eqz\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\arnav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coyz2eqz\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\arnav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-9oavdegz'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: This will not help any one identify the issue. First say what program was run and how it was run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows)

Comment: Include all the details like project url, try to add more tags and other details as well.

Comment: was the following tutorial followed https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist ?.