# Python not recognizing pkg-config has been installed

Tags: python, windows, pip, pkg-config, binance

I am unable to get python to recognize that pkg-config has been installed.  The end goal is to be able to download the python-binance-chain library: https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance-chain but at this moment when I use pip to install the library I receive the following error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\jpeterson\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\jpeterson\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0459uu9t\\secp256k1_ba55524266274c10b617991dff5a4d87\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\jpeterson\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0459uu9t\\secp256k1_ba55524266274c10b617991dff5a4d87\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\jpeterson\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fzc7jgqc'
         cwd: C:\Users\jpeterson\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0459uu9t\secp256k1_ba55524266274c10b617991dff5a4d87\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    'pkg-config' is required to install this package. Please see the README for details.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have downloaded the following pkg-config files:

1. pkg-config_0.26-1_win32
2. glib_2.28.8-1_win32
3. gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32

However but I don't know where they need to be for python to recognize that pkg-config has been installed.  I have referred to the following stackoverflow inquiry: [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows) but would ideally not have to install a number of different tools, especially considering I am not sure if they will enable the end goal of installing the python-binance-chain library.