# gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory Windows

Tags: c, windows, gtk, gtk3

I have spent the past few days on and off scouring the internet for solutions to this problem, and every solution I have found just brings up more issues for me. I am inclined to believe this is because I am using windows, as opposed to using linux or similar, but I can't confirm.

Here is what I have tried:

1. $sudo ...

This results results in me getting the message: `'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. This seems to be a command that is not on windows and has no clear replacement in this context.

2. 'pkg-config'

I have seen various different versions of what to do and I can't remember which I have tried and which I have not. It does consistently give me the message `pkg-config: No such file or directory`

I'm really not sure where to go, as everything I have found has basically just been giving me one of these 2 solutions, but not really explaining what they do or where to use them. It is entirely possible that I am simply trying to do it in the wrong directory but don't realize it.

If it matters, this is the code I have. It's pretty sparse, as I just wanted to make sure gtk was working at all.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *button;

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
```

I'm sure that this question has been answered somewhere else, but after hours of searching I couldn't find it, so I'm posting here.

EDIT: It seems y'all think I installed it incorrectly, and while that is possible and I have looked at what has been sent to me and tried it, I still don't know how to use GTK. The code I've compiled still has the same error.

I believe the problem is related to not having `pkg-config` (as I stated above), and the only information I have found on how to get `pkg-config` is using the `sudo` command, which I believe is a Linux exclusive, or at least not native to Windows

Comment: https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows

Comment: Take a look here GTK on [Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUJFYOCbuDg&list=PLN_MPJUQgPVopEfWiFX88_zUzk08ZdrIc).

Comment: GTK is mostly used in Linux afaik but its cross-platform. What params do you use to build your script? If all else fails, try including `#include <windows.h>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

here is the guide to set up GTK it on windows:
[GTK official documentation](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/)

if you want to install pkg-config on windows:
[How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows#22363820)

to compile your code, here is what the documentation says:

`gcc $( pkg-config --cflags gtk4 ) -o example-0 example-0.c $( pkg-config --libs gtk4)`