# How can I solve this "cannot remove *.log" error in a GoLang backend project?

Tags: c++, go, compilation

I have a GoLang backend project. I have an issue when building this project.

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- vips vips vips vips
pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

I am working on Windows 10.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Marked as a possible duplicate: [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution from this link.

[How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows)

You have to install G++ and other relevant libraries on your computer and register the system environment variable.