# go fails to run with database imports on Windows with cannot find -loci collect2.exe error

Tags: go, ld

i'm working on Windows 10

in my code i imported oracle package as in http://go-database-sql.org/importing.html

```
import (
"database/sql"
_ "github.com/mattn/go-oci8"
```

)

then i followed the instruction to install oracle plugin as in
https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8

i installed all written in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363820/15190000

Then when i ran "go build -x main.go" i get this error:

C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1

> c:/bin/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> cannot find -loci collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**no matter what i do i keep getting the same error "cannot find -loci"**

under my C:\bin\oracle_client\instantclient_12_2\sdk\lib\msvc i do find oci.lib

also when i call "pkg-config --cflags --libs oci8" i see the oci8.pc file

Comment: You need Go to inform ld.exe (the linker) to add `C:\bin\oracle_client\instantclient_12_2\sdk\lib\msvc` to the list of directories to check for libraries. E.g. via envvar: `@SET CGO_LDFLAGS=-LC:\bin\oracle_client\instantclient_12_2\sdk\lib\msvc` if you build with a script (.bat).

Comment: If you choose to use a .bat, might also throw in a `@SETLOCAL` as first line so you don't pollute your terminal's env vars.