# Unable to install older versions of kivy(1.11.1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy

I was trying to download a specific version of kivy on windows 10
Using the command  `pip install kivy==1.11.1`

But unfortunately its throwing me the an error every time
I tried on python 3.8 and 3.9

Error

```
    PS C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5> pip install kivy==1.11.1
Collecting kivy==1.11.1
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\
DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xzh5pn7u\\kivy_fa50084c889744ab947ceda05f1f5068\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-
install-xzh5pn7u\\kivy_fa50084c889744ab947ceda05f1f5068\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.
StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'
"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-31ligwpm'
         cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xzh5pn7u\kivy_fa50084c889744ab947ceda05f1f5068\
    Complete output (395 lines):
    WARNING: Skipping page https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip because the HEAD request got Content-Type: application/zip.The only supported
 Content-Type is text/html
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Us
ers\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-shrhx05n\\cython_6ddf5340cd6c4d32af23f49c9f16fd57\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\
\pip-wheel-shrhx05n\\cython_6ddf5340cd6c4d32af23f49c9f16fd57\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) els
e io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'
exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-z42_ozzm'
           cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-shrhx05n\cython_6ddf5340cd6c4d32af23f49c9f16fd57\
      Complete output (321 lines):
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      running bdist_wheel
      packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 77, in fetch_build_egg
         raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['C:\\Users\\DELL\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject5\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-versio
n-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpmf8k8ffx', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/arc
hive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)
    
    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)
    
    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)
    
    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    
    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/4d/3f8a720f561dc1eabe036c0d87c6ce9d02823275391265538e606f45e37a/Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz#sha256=4d0e596f
74271e901b551f77661dde238df4765484fce9f5d1c72e8022984e84 (from https://pypi.org/simple/kivy/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info C
heck the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy==1.11.1 (from versions: 1.0.1a0, 1.0.2a0, 1.0.3a0, 1.0.4b0, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9
, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.11.1,
2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0rc4, 2.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy==1.11.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
PS C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5>
```

Note: ive discarded some lines form the error due to stackoverflow's character limit

Comment: Not sure it is supported on older version of python. Did you try kivy 2.0.0 ?

Comment: I actually want kivy ver 1.11.1

Comment: Can you successfully install anything on your system using `pip`?

Comment: Yes i installed kivy version 2.0 successfully, but failed when i tried installing 1.11.1

Comment: Did you uninstall kivy 2.0 first? See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.11.1/installation/installation-windows.html#updating-kivy-from-a-previous-release).

Comment: I've deleted all dependencies and kivy manually and tried installing ver 1.11.1 ,it still shows me error

Comment: From the log, it seems `pkg-config` is missing, try installing it.

However, I don't think you can do that without additional programs installed. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows) for more info

Comment: I've finally fixed the problem by downgrading python to ver 3.7 ,

Comment: But it seems to be an older version , is there any way that i can run/install kivy 1.11.1 on python 3.9.???

Answer (score 0):

**Kivy 1.11. 0 is the last release that supports Python 2. Now that python is installed, open the Command line and make sure python is available by typing python --version .
It's for Python 2 and You're On Python 3
and You want to downgrade for that!**