# How can I find out which package is missing for conan?

Tags: conan

I am trying to install an environment using conan. I receive the message

```
opengl/system: Already installed!
ERROR: opengl/system: Error in package_info() method, line 60
    pkg_config.fill_cpp_info(self.cpp_info, is_system=self.settings.os != "FreeBSD")
    ConanException: pkg-config command ['pkg-config', '--print-provides', 'gl', '--print-errors'] failed with error: Command 'pkg-config --print-provides gl --print-errors' returned non-zero exit status 127.
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
```

This says me a lot of information, except that which package is not yet installed.
How can I find out that?

Comment: clearly it says `pkg-config: not found`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows

Comment: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/14909

Comment: Thanks. I did not think it is a package name. And a question: Why conan does not install it?

Comment: I receive the message "xorg/system: ERROR: while executing system_requirements(): System requirements: 'libx11-xcb-dev, libfontenc-dev, libxaw7-dev, libxcomposite-dev, libxcursor-dev, libxdamage-dev, libxfixes-dev, libxi-dev, libxinerama-dev, libxkbfile-dev, libxmu-dev, libxmuu-dev, libxpm-dev, libxrandr-dev, libxrender-dev, libxres-dev, libxss-dev, libxtst-dev, libxv-dev, libxvmc-dev, libxxf86vm-dev, libxcb-render0-dev, libxcb-render-util0-dev, libxcb-xkb-dev, , etc' are missing" is it my mistake that conan does not install these packages? (I do install manually, but do not like to do so)

Comment: Sorry, I mean that package names used to be quoted.

Comment: The ``opengl/system`` is not a regular recipe, it is a "system" wrapper recipe. It wraps some system libs for opengl, calling system package manager to install them if necessary, like ``mesa-libGL-devel`` (but not by default, users should opt-in for an actual install). The recipe assumes that ``pkg-config`` is installed in the system. If anything, it would be a recipe responsibility, not a Conan responsibility.

Comment: Also the error message should be saying more things, like: ``because tools.system.package_manager:mode is {}.Please update packages manually or set tools.system.package_manager:mode``. So you don't need to install manually, but define the Conan configuration to opt-in and Conan will install those packages.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help. I attempted to find something like 'tools.system' in .conan, but no avail.