# Problems building GTK 4 library for windows 10

Tags: gtk

I need to use the GTK 4 library to create the GUI of my program, I need to include it in a Microsoft Visual Studio C++ project.

I use windows 10 64 bit.

So looking a bit on the net the only thing I found [that](https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2021/03/18/build-and-run-gtk-4-applications-with-visual-studio/) I trocato is this.

I performed all the steps described in the guide:

1. I have Python installed (V. 3.11.4)
2. I have GIT installed
3. I opened "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022"
4. I created the src folder
5. I entered the src folder
6. I configured (logged in) git
7. I installed Meson using pip
8. I fetched GTK from git
9. I entered the gtk folder created earlier
10. I tried to build GTK 4 with all its dependencies, and this is where I ran into my problem

Indeed after executing the command: `meson setup build --prefix C:/gnome`.

I get that some libraries have not been found, as a value of some results I get NO *(I don't know if it's normal)*, and I get the following error towards the end:

```
modules\media\meson.build:42:16: ERROR: Dependency lookup for gstreamer-player-1.0 with method 'pkgconfig' failed: Pkg-config binary for machine 1 not found. Giving up.
```

i put all the output inside [this](https://mega.nz/file/Rz9WCQbZ#PVzr8a9QPiR6h5G4UG9tc_b3-J3ob8GWf-zBj6EeQqE) text file.

I tried to re-do all the steps several times but I still get the same errors, I also tried to go ahead the same, then I ran the command: `meson compile -C build` but I got the following error:

```
C:\src\gtk>meson compile -C build

ERROR: Current directory is not a meson build directory: `C:\src\gtk\build`.
Please specify a valid build dir or change the working directory to it.
It is also possible that the build directory was generated with an old
meson version. Please regenerate it in this case.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need Pkg-config binary as a dependency. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1711338/4409163).