# How to build libpqxx libraries in C++ with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, postgresql, cmake, libpqxx

I am trying to develop a database app using PostgreSQL with VS2022 in C++.  I have successfully installed Postgres 16.1-1 software and a data directory in my Documents directory.  I unzipped libpqxx-7.8.1 but don't see libraries so I am now trying to create a VS Solution (.SLN) using CMake to do that.  It had trouble finding pkg-config.exe but I solved that by referencing Thomas Weller's 8 step process at [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922) to get that working.  I seem to have at least 2 problems remaining that prevent me from generating the .SLN file.  Using a Windows 11 CMD window, I navigate to Documents/libpqxx-7.8.1/ and execute "cmake ."  Then,--

1. CMake reports "Could NOT find PostgreSQL (missing: PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR).  That include subdirectory is there under the Program Files\PostgreSQL directory.  I don't have any idea how to help it find all of the PostgreSQL installation.  Do I need to edit something?
2. After successfully finding pkg-config.exe (v 0.26), the module 'libpq' was not found.  CMake reports--
   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:829 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
   cmake/config.cmake:35 (pkg_check_modules)
   CMakeLists.txt:27 (include)
   Do I need to edit something? or download something?

I notice there are two CMakeLists.txt files in the tree.  One in the libpqxx-7.8.1 (root) directory and one in its src subdirectory.  Am I correct in using the one in the root?

Comment: `I have successfully installed Postgres 16.1-1` Not sure what you were doing, but you should install Postgres dev packages with libraries. Consider using vcpkg.

Comment: ***Am I correct in using the one in the root?*** Most likely. The root one should use the CMakeLists.txt in the src folder likely with an add_subdirectory() command.

Comment: ***That include subdirectory is there under the Program Files\PostgreSQL directory.*** One way you can tell it is to use cmake-gui and edit the `PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR` variable in the GUI to the Include directory and then configure and generate again.

Comment: @273K I installed with the Postgres Windows x86-64 installer from the EDB page.  Libraries are there and on the VS2022 paths but VS has problems linking.  I have not seen installations that distinguish a development version.  I also do not see vcpkg files for Postgres like vcpkg.json anywhere.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/libpqxx. https://vcpkg.io/en/packages libpqxx |Version: 7.8.1 .\vcpkg install libpqxx

Comment: @273K Also, I'm not trying to build Postgres libraries. I'm trying to build libpqxx.

Comment: @273K vcpkg seemed to work but the build failed.  There are many warnings for universal characters not representable on Windows code page 1252.  But also, there are 88 LNK2019 errors that I didn't expect. I wouldn't think I should get any of those when building the library.  I looked and noted that the github directory has a subdirectory.  When I double-click to look at that, I get the message, "Sorry, we had to truncate this directory to 1000 files. 1,370 entries were omitted from the list. Latest commit info may be omitted."  What does that mean?  Is the package I got incomplete?

Comment: @drescherjm I tried your suggestion but ran into problems probably caused by my unfamiliarity with the tool.  Tried the vcpkg suggestion and ran into problems there too.  Perseverance should prevail in the end so the saga will continue.